# Como descobrir (e capturar) o usuário que executa o PHP?

Tags: php, apache

Eu sei que o comando `phpinfo()` retorna isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quero saber se existe alguma forma de capturar essa informação (user/group) numa variável.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descobri. Dá pra fazer isso usando:

```
$uid = posix_getuid();
$userinfo = posix_getpwuid($uid);
print_r($userinfo);
```

Ou:

```
print posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];
```

Fonte: [How to check what user php is running as?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771662/6054930).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `$_SERVER['USER']`.

Se uma pessoa acessasse *site.com/arquivo.php*, o `$_SERVER['USER']` seria o `nginx`, por exemplo. Enquanto isso se fosse executado, via SSH (php /www/arquivo.php) ele seria o respectivo nome do usuário conectado ao SSH, `root` por exemplo.

Teste isso usando:

```
echo $_SERVER['USER'];
```

Você pode fazer por exemplo:

```
if($_SERVER['USER'] === 'www-data'){
//É acessado via apache
}else{
//Não acessado por apache
}
```

Comment: Acho que `Apache` não retorna `$_SERVER['USER']`. O meu não retorna. Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que `www-data` não é um usuário exclusivo do `Apache`. De qualquer forma, `$_SERVER` não vai retornar o que eu preciso, pois tem referências do script, e não do serviço.